# Celery - Returning results from nested chains

Tags: python, celery

I am trying to use nested chains within Celery tasks. Below is a contrived example of the type of problem I am facing.

add_tasks.py:

```
from celery import Celery, chain

app = Celery('add_tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

app.conf.CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost/0'

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

@app.task
def inner_chain(x):
    # range parameter could change
    task_list = [add.s(x,x)] + [add.s(x) for _ in xrange(10)] 
    return chain(*task_list)() #.get()

@app.task
def outer_chain():
    return chain(
            add.s(1,1),
            inner_chain.s()
    )() #.get()
```

add_tester.py:

```
from add_tasks import outer_chain

r = outer_chain.delay()

print r.get()
print r.get().get()
print r.get().get().get()
```

Currently I would obtain output of the form:

```
Result-ID
Result-ID
Result
```

Uncommenting the .get() in my two chain tasks causes deadlocks, and causes a warning about running synchronous subtasks, but I don't know how else to pass the results of subtasks around.

What's the correct way to do this sort of thing? Do I need to use apply_async in my tasks?